# Conditions for $\iint f(x,y)\;x^2dx\;dy\le\left(\iint f(x,y)\;x\;dx\;dy\right)^2$ to be true

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $f:\bf{R}^2\rightarrow\bf{R}$. What conditions on $f(x,y)$ are needed for this to be true?
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\;x^2dx\;dy\le\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\;x\;dx\;dy\right)^2
$$

where $f(x,y)$ is a probability density and satisfies:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\;dx\;dy=1
$$
and $$
f(x,y)>0
$$

Comment: Is the right-hand side missing an integral sign?

Comment: Let f(x,y) = 0 then it is true. And this is a condition. You should probably ask for suf. and nec. conditions.

Comment: @joriki oops, thanks for pointing out. I've corrected that.

Comment: Do you have constraint on $\iint f(x,y) dx dy$? Do you have constraint on sign of $f$ (it is obvious the inequality is satisfied when $f$ non-positive)?

Comment: Note that the dependency on $y$ isn't really entering into it, since you can write this as

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\mathrm dy\right)x^2\,\mathrm dx\le\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\mathrm dy\right)x\,\mathrm dx\right)^2\;,
$$

so introducing $\displaystyle g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy$ reduces it to

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)x^2\,\mathrm dx\le\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)x\,\mathrm dx\right)^2\;.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the clarification that $f(x,y)$ is a probability density, we have that $g(x)$ (as defined in my comment) is also a probability density. In that case the inequality can only be satisfied if equality holds, since the reverse inequality holds for probability densities. Since the difference between the two sides is the variance, equality holds if and only if the variance vanishes. If $f(x,y)$ is a continuous density function (and not e.g. a delta distribution), the variance cannot vanish, so in that case the inequality never holds.